# Text box Rendering in JSF 2.0

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I have a text box where the end user has to enter the number of text boxes that should be rendered. Based on the number entered, the number of text boxes have to render dynamically in row-format.

Also in the newly rendered row formatted text boxes the values entered has to be identified with correct backing bean when it goes to the next page.

Any suggestions on where to start or how to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<h:inputText>` to ask enduser for input.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.number}" />
```

You can use `<h:commandButton>` to let user submit a form.

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
```

You can use `List<T>` to have a collection of items.

```
private List<Item> items;

public void submit() {
    items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        items.add(new Item());
    }
}
```

You can use `<h:dataTable>` to present it in rows.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <h:column>
        <h:inputText value="#{item.value}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

The submitted values will just end up right there in `items`.

Comment: your answer is GREAT, but suppose that if end user wants to render 5 text boxes dynamically, at that time how to bind value for those all dynamically rendered 5 <h:inputText> in <h:dataTable>.

Comment: Uh, the answer already shows that. The input value is bound to the iterated item.

Comment: Why i am getting this: "value="#{item.value}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'item' resolved to null" error.

Comment: It's caused elsewhere than in the code provided in the answer (in other words: you didn't use the exact code as provided in the answer, or you modified it too much without actually understanding what you're doing). Press `Ask Question` instead of hijacking other's question for this.

Comment: thanks @BalusC .Suppose without submitting the page ,Using Ajax i need to render the new text boxes once i enter the input number. I gues we can use f:ajax listener attribute but how to set the bean number property without submitting the page ?

Comment: Give the `<h:inputText>` an `id` and specify it in `<f:ajax execute>`. Or just use `<f:ajax execute="@form">`.

Comment: On an additional note the  ajax call happens successfully but if i again change the bean.Number value and make an ajax call "viewExpired" exception arises even though we havent navigated to a different view . My bean is in viewScope and is implementing Serializable .Any idea on that ?